# Implementation standard of retransmission scheduling in a communication protocol

Tags: networking, timestamp, protocols, communication

So I am implementing a communication protocol over UDP, which obviously means that I will be managing all error handling and retransmission myself. My originial plan was to have a timestamp as part of the header in my packets and keep all non-acknowledged packets in a retransmission queue. Then I would maintain a round trip delay time and a round trip time out (how long to wait for acknowledgement before retransmitting the packet), by measuring the time a packet was acknowledged and compare this time with the timestamp for the packet in the retransmission queue.

Someone then told me that having timestamps as part of packet headers is normally something that is used in streaming protocols, since timing is of big importance in those cases (timing is of no importance in my case). However, I did a little research, and it seems like UDT uses timestamps in this way although UDT is not a streaming protocol. Actually, what I am trying to implement is kinda similar to UDT.

I guess I could easily remove the timestamp field of the header, and just keep track of the sending times of the packets in another queue running parallel to my retransmission queue.

I'm just curious to hear what you guys think?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use something like zeromq and implement a protocol? It is very error prone.

Comment: well, I didn't know about zeromq until just now ;) actually it is a project for my university I am doing, so I don't think I am allowed to use something like zeromq. But it looks very interesting!